# Python & Django on a Mac: Illegal hardware instruction

Tags: python, django, homebrew

Here is my issue: 
I installed Python and Django on my mac. When I run "django-admin.py startproject test1" I get this error:

1 11436 illegal hardware instruction django-admin.py startproject
test1  (the number is always different)

I've tested with multiple Django versions, and this only happens with version 1.4 and higher...1.3 works fine.

I've been searching the web like crazy for the past week, and couldn't find anything regarding this issue with django so I assume the problem is not Django itself but something else. This is only on my mac at home, at work where I user Ubuntu works fine.

I tried to reinstall my entire system and this are the only things I have installed right now: 
- Command line tools 
- Homebrew 
- Python & pip (w/ Homebrew) 
- Git (w/ Homebrew) 
- zsh (.oh-my-zsh shell)

I set up my virtualenv and install django 1.5.1 -- the same issue still appears.

I'm out of options for now since nothing I found resolves my problem, I'm hoping someone has some knowledge about this error.

I appreciate all the help, and thanks.

This is the python crash log:

> > Process:         Python [2597] Path:            /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
> >     Identifier:      Python Version:         2.7.4 (2.7.4) Code Type:
> >     X86-64 (Native) Parent Process:  zsh [2245] User ID:         501
>
> Date/Time:       2013-05-05 20:53:19.899 +0200 OS Version:      Mac OS
>   X 10.8.3 (12D78) Report Version:  10
>
> Interval Since Last Report:          16409 sec Crashes Since Last
>   Report:           2 Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1 Anonymous
>   UUID:                      D859C141-544F-3473-1A13-F984DB2F8CBE
>
> Crashed Thread:  0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
>
> Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL) Exception Codes:
>   0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000

Comment: installing django is not a programming question, and thus shall better be on superuser or on askdifferent. my 2cts.

Comment: Ok, I'll ask there...Just thought more people would be familiar with this problem here since it happens in other programming scenarios rather than the one I have here. It's just what I'm stuck on. (I'm familiar with installing django, and thats not what I'm trying to learn here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that kind of problem smells like architecture mess. You may try to execute a 64bit library from a 32bit interpreter or vice versa… As you're using homebrew, you shall be really careful of which interpreter you're using, what is your path etc… Maybe you shall trace your program to know more exactly where it fails, so you can pinpoint what is *actually* failing. It is very unlikely django that fails, but more something that django uses. For someone to help you, you need to dig more closely to your failing point, and give more context about what is failing *beyond* django.

Comment: Yes I figured it's not Django that fails, It's just that there is not much info about the error except just saying "Illegal hardware instruction".

This is my PATH var: 
usr/local/bin:/usr/local/share/python:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

I've tried to use both 32 and 64 bit python inside a virtualenv, but still I get this exception. And python crashes.

Comment: Did you fix it? Also facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same, but went around this issue by using Docker/docker-compose.